# 10Gb ISCSI to 1Gb server port

Tags: iscsi, 10gbethernet

I have this setup in mind.

- Md3800i 4 10GBps Iscsi.
- 2 del r730 4 1Gbps ports.

I will use this storage to backups and low profile mass storage. 
So i don't won't to put HBAs in the server.

Looking at the manuals of the storage i see that iscsi ports are standard RJ45 connectors.

So my question is can I connect the 1Gbps server ports directly to de 10Gbps iscsi in ports using standard cat6a utp cables and configure a 1Gbps network using vmware initiator?

**UPDATE**

The interfases came up without issues and I manage to configure ISCSI without issues.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Technically, iSCSI is a protocol and does not specify a specific physical interface (e.g., RJ-45 eithernet). You can run iSCSI over fiber or really any medium that handles TCP/IP.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, perhaps I messed up things a little bit the question was more oriented to if the network interfases will come up.

Answer (score 2):

This is only about 75% of an answer but it seems too much an answer for just a comment:

- Direct connection is supported by Dell for this array
- Every 10 GbE interface I've seen so far will auto-sense 1 Gbps and can be configured to only operate at 1 Gbps

So the short answer is "**Yes**", and the lacking 25% is the barest slim chance that somehow the MD3800i won't run its 10 GbE interfaces at 1 Gbps, but I really don't think that will be a problem (I can't find confirmation online, though).

If this is a brand new MD3800i then you should have free implementation support with a Dell tech who will guide you through the connectivity all the way to configuring MPIO. If it is brand new and you are just hearing about implementation support for the first time from me, contact your reseller.

It's not clear how saavy you are about iSCSI storage so please forgive this next part if you already know: If you can't get implementation support somehow, then make sure you research best practices for configuring the iSCSI network interfaces. Just off the top of my head (from a recent config very simular to this I recently did), best practice for the R730 iSCSI interfaces will be to max out the Tx and Rx buffers and of course enable jumbo frames. And do not team any iSCSI NICs. The MPIO drivers from Dell will handle multiple simultaneous connections.

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of 10Gb Ethernet. If your Md3800i host support the 10Gb BaseT standard (normal copper-based RJ45 cables), yes: you can connect the DELL 730 ports without problems. If the 10Gb/s ports are not a RJ45 ones (es: SFP+) you can not connect them with a simple ethernet cable to the R730.

Comment: He already stated in his question that the manual states it has standard RJ45 connections.

Comment: Fair enough. I missed it...